# Sqlite commands in Room is not highlighted

Tags: android, android-room

I have a trouble with Sqlite commands in Room

I need this

[image]

But I get this

[image]

Comment: Is movie table annotated with @Entity ?

Comment: Yeah movie table has an @Entity

Comment: just change room version in build.gradle(app). [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75743106/14670277)