# android studio not recognizing(change in color) and suggesting SQLite commands in room @Query() annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

Student.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "student_table")
data class Student(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id:Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName:String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName:String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "roll_no") val rollNo:Int?
)
```

StudentDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface StudentDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM student_table")
    fun getAll(): List<Student>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE roll_no LIKE :roll LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun findByRoll(roll: Int): Student
```

Build Output(31 tasks were UP-TO-DATE, i didn't mentioned them below)

```
> Task :app:createDebugVariantModel UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect
> Task :app:assembleDebug
```

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 19s
37 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 31 up-to-date

Build Analyzer results available
```

In StudentDao.kt file @Query() annotation not recognizing SQLite query ex. student_table(as table name) & not highlighting SQLite queries like SELECT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71839798/sqlite-commands-in-room-is-not-highlighted i found this same question but answer is not given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem by trying different versions of room. previously i was using latest version which was 2.5.0 as of march 2023

```
def room_version = "2.4.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply compile the project, that will raise most actual issues in the build log.

It could be simplest to accept that at times the underlying checking within the editor is not always fully comprehensive. I find that change code then compile (CTRL + F9) and then check the build log is the most effective policy.

Comment: please check my Build Output added in question   @MikeT

Comment: @sandesh says the build is successful so no issues with the Room code. Not at all sure about the NO SOURCE but you could worse check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171972/build-is-success-but-no-sources-to-compile

Comment: Db is working fine but my question is why editor is not able to recognize and differentiate a query with color? as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71839798/sqlite-commands-in-room-is-not-highlighted